# Use TestFlight without Developer Certificate

Tags: macos, iphone, xcode, development

I have developed an Xcode iOS app, but can I use it on my TestFlight without a Paid Dev Cert?

Comment: You will need a paid developer certificate anyway sooner or later, why do you want to use TestFlight without one?

Comment: I dont want to get it in the AppStore, i just need it for private use

Comment: If you just need it for yourself, you can get a certificate with the free dev account. Probably won't work with TestFlight, but you won't need it for private use anyway.

Comment: So how to get a free one?and how do i add it to my iPhone?

Comment: Start at https://developer.apple.com/programs/

Comment: Where you able to get your app on Testflight without Xcode? If so how did you get do? When I archive my app it has the App Store greyed out.